# converting date string to timestamp

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have date strings like '1997-05-07 ' ('year-month-day') and when I try to convert it to timestamp (in order to compare them and have some plots I need to convert them ) I get this error :

```
ValueError: time data '1997-07-05' does not match format '%y-%m-%d'
```

what I try is :

```
 time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime('1997-07-05','%y-%m-%d').timetuple())
```

Comment: `'%y'` is a two-digit year (e.g. `97`); you want `'%Y'` (note capital letter) for a four-digit year. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%y` format expects the year without century as a decimal padded number.  If you want to parse `1997`, you need to use `%Y`.

You can view more information on how `strptime` works [in the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

You have your format wrong - `%y` matches only 2-digit year. If you want "full" year, you have to use `%Y`:

```
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime('1997-07-05','%Y-%m-%d').timetuple())
868053600.0
```

Comment: @Pari please, dont ask in comments - create new question.